# Sequences vs matrices

Tags: sequences-and-series

Numbers from sequences such as the Fibonacci sequence $(0,1,1,2,3,5,...)$ can be put into a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0\:\:1\:\:1\:\:2\:\:3\:\:5\:\:...\end{bmatrix}$ and since matrices can be multiplied by numbers, you can get a new matrix $2\times \begin{bmatrix}0\:\:1\:\:1\:\:2\:\:3\:\:5\:\:...\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\:\:2\:\:2\:\:4\:\:6\:\:10\:\:...\end{bmatrix}$. Unless I'm missing some information, Isn't it correct that sequences can't be multiplied by numbers? If this is true, what is the point of having special notation for sequences and why don't we write them as matrices?

**Edit**: same goes for ordered pairs (e.g. $(x,y)\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$)

Comment: You say it's more useful to write as a matrix. Could you expand a bit on why that is?

Comment: I don't follow your question. A sequence is typically a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to some subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which contains infinitely many terms so cannot reasonably be contained within a matrix.

Comment: What do you mean more useful? Matrices are a way to represent data, same goes for sequences.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't clear in my original post; I've just made an edit. I meant isn't it more useful because you can add, subtract, or even multiply matrices but you can't do that to sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would anyone ever want to use order lists (tuples) when we can represent them as matrices for which the operations of addition and multiplication is defined?

The answer is simply that imposing unnecessary structure on a mathematical object is often not desirable.

Perhaps my ordered list represents three 4-digit product codes (1423 5523 8901). I would probably never want to add this to another list of three 4-digit product codes, so it would be pointless to store this information in the form of a structure on which addition is defined.